# How to retrieve gmail filters list via "Google Apps Email Settings API"?

Tags: gmail, google-api, google-email-settings-api

I'd like to retrieve all mail filters list of a given google account and eventually delete some of them.

I've found only the API for adding filters, but not the ones for listing and deleting.
I think it's strange but I am not able to find that APIs,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. There is no API call to export / retrieve Gmail filters. You can only create filters via the Email Settings API. The user can export their filters from the UI though:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/new-in-labs-filter-importexport.html